# Issues with If Else statements

Tags: python, datetime

I am learning Python from scratch in the sense that I do not have much coding background. In this particular exercise, I am given the task of taking a text file, removing the spaces and commas, then printing it out as seven individual lines (which I have done.) Now, that I finished the task, I need to display real, incrementing time before the individual int on each line, while also adding a day to the line reading 'blank blank.'

I've tried several approaches and cannot seem to get both criteria to occur simultaneously. Here is the code I have written:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFile.txt", "r") as inp:
    with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFileOutput.txt", "w") as outp:

    clock = datetime.now()

    for line in inp.readlines():
        total = 0
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(",")
        for part in parts:

            try:
                num = int(part)
                total += num

            except ValueError:
                total = (" ".join(parts))
                break

    #for line in inp:

    if total == int:
        total_time = clock + timedelta(seconds = 1)
        print (clock + timedelta (seconds = 1))
    else:
        total_time = clock + timedelta(days = 1)
        print (clock + timedelta (days = 1))

    outp.write("%s: " % total_time)

    outp.write('{}\n'.format(total))
```

And here is 'RandomFile:'

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
blank,blank
5,6
6,7
```

With the code I have provided, here is the 'RandomFileOutput' that I receive:

2016-06-28 13:47:56.106000: 13

Up until I added the last if, else statement I was receiving the output of:

```
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 3
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 5
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 7
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 9
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: blank blank
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 11
2016-06-28 13:51:19.709000: 13
```

Can anybody shed some light on what I've done wrong?

Comment: What is `total == int` supposed to do? I don't see where you're assigning (shadowing) the built-in `int` function and I don't understand why your `total` would ever compare equal to it?

Comment: `if total == int`? are you trying to test if total is greater than 0?

Comment: should it be if type(total) is int?, because otherwise its a string of the parts?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use that to call the numbers from each line of the text file. Quite honestly, I am really unsure of what I'm doing.

Comment: well you should be using `isinstance(total, int)` or better still enclose everything in a `try`, `except` block, the except block will contain everything in your current else block of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your indentation is wrong, and you should be checking for the type of the total, not total==int:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

with open("RandomFile.txt", "r") as inp:
    with open("RandomFileOutput.txt", "w") as outp:

        clock = datetime.now()

        for i, line in enumerate(inp.readlines()):
            total = 0
            line = line.strip()
#             print(line)
            parts = line.split(",")
            for part in parts:

                try:
                    num = int(part)
                    total += num

                except ValueError:
                    total = (" ".join(parts))
                    break

            #for line in inp:
            print(type(total))
            if type(total) == int:
                total_time = clock + timedelta(seconds = 1)
                print (clock + timedelta(seconds = 1))
            else:
                total_time = clock + timedelta(days = 1)
                print (clock + timedelta(days = 1))
            outp.write("%s: " % total_time)

            outp.write('{}\n'.format(total))
```

prints:

```
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
<class 'str'>
2016-06-29 16:12:10.967791
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
<class 'int'>
2016-06-28 16:12:11.967791
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vince! Learning this language without guidance is proving to be tricky

Comment: Out of curiosity: if I wanted to continue the change in date (i.e. after changing from 28 to 29, keep 29) how would I do so?

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of the time Delta that is outside the scope of the for Loop